# How do I add a new plugin without recompiling in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-rcp

How can I add an unknown plugin to a deployed RCP application without recompiling the application?

I want to:

1. deploy RCP application.
2. create a new plugin (language plugin).
3. drop the plugin into the plugin folder.
4. ???

Finally, the deployed application should use the new plugin.

When modifying the *config.ini* file and manually adding all the plugins, it works, but I don't want to manually edit the config file. How can I do this automatically?

Comment: You need to use the Eclipse p2 install director to ensure things are installed properly see [p2 install director](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html) and [command line install using p2 director](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/04/04/installing-eclipse-features-via-the-command-line-with-the-p2-director/)

Comment: I don't complettly understand. I have to enter a command into the commandline to add a language plugin? Are there any examples. The code pieces make not much sense to me :/ I don't have any "update sites". I simply copy a plugin in the plugin folder and want to use it. Is there no such thing as simply: Uee all the plugins in the plugin folder onn startup?

Comment: At one time it was possible to just copy to the plugins directory but this has not been the case for some time.